# Make qTip not disappear when click the another qTip

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I used the qtip2 jquery plugin.How to make qTip not disappear when click the another qTip.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `hide: fixed` property. This allows you to click on tooltips without them going away. - http://qtip2.com/options#hide.fixed

Usually it is used with the `hide: delay` property as well so that when the user moves the mouse from the trigger to the tooltip, he has time to move to the tooltip without it being hidden first.

```js
$("#red-box").qtip({
    content: "this will stay for 1 second after you leave the box or tooltip",
    hide: {
        delay: 1000,
        fixed: true
    }
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/25eydrn3/1/